# EF not returning all data in query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project I have a table called UserInfo (will be abbreviated for purposes of this post) that looks like this:

```
public class UserInfo()
{
    public virtual string FirstName{get;set;}
    public virtual string LastName{get;set;}
    public virtual string Email{get;set;}
}
```

I am populating a PagedList which is a class to help enable paging of my data. In the controller I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    IRepository<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo> profile = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>>();

    const int pageSize = 10;

    IQueryable<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo> profiles = profile.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.LastName).AsQueryable();

    var pagedCustomers = new PagedList<Clusteris.Data.UserInfo>(profiles, page ?? 0, pageSize);

    return View(pagedCustomers);
}
```

Here's PagedList:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public bool HasPrevious { get { return (PageIndex > 0); } }
    public bool HasNext { get { return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages); } }

    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }
}
```

That works fine except for one ting, it's only returning the email value, not first & last name (though I know they have values in them). Any idea why only 1 value is being returned?

Comment: So does profiles have data in it for those fields when you make the `profile.GetAll()` call?

Comment: Nope, Last name and first name are null and I cant figure out why it will get the email but not names

Comment: Is UserInfo a generated class from EF or something you wrote yourself?

Comment: Offhand it sounds like the mapping is screwed up - typically I end up getting null values when that is the case.

Comment: UserInfo is a table in the database. but I found what's wrong. Someone has been putting in test data and not providing first/last name & phone, thus the null valuesl

Comment: Glad you found it.  Have a good one!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and taking the time to help me. You have a god one as well

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get NinJect or some other for m of DI. It drives me bonkers to see an instantiation of a repository in an action method

Comment: Question, if this has been resolved by finding the NULL data how would I go about marking this issue solved?

Comment: Add your own answer and then pick it as the answer